# ASP.Net Web API writing to SQL Server does not update date appended column in database automatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have an Entity Framework (EF) database-first project written in C# which saves data to a SQL Server database.

The database contains a `Date_Appended` column to record the date/time for when the record is first added, an `Author` column to record the database user that submitted the record, and a `Date_Modified` column to record the date/time when the record is modified.

Even when I delete these columns from the EF model the database record still shows null and the fields are not automatically updated. How do I get the database to auto populate these columns?

Comment: You removed some fields from model, now you want to remove these fields from database? Do you want to sync the schema between the model and the database?

Comment: Might be obvious but have you verified the table is setup properly by manually inserting a record without those columns specified to verify it does what you want?

Comment: please add the code where you are deleting the columns

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Yes I have manually inserted a record and verified that the date appended, date modified, and author fields are automatically populated by the database

Comment: @DanNguyen I want those fields to be auto-populated so I deleted them from the EF mappings so ASP.net web api doesn't submit null for those fields. But I still get null in the DB because the DB still won't auto-populate those fields

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see the actual SQL being sent by EF to the database?  That might give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: Are you using code first migration?